# Transfer variable to other class

Tags: flutter, variables, dart

I am trying to get a list from class to the other. But I want it to only be transferred after it has got a value assigned from a Future. Is there a way to do so (something like a `setState` method that acts across classes) My code is here:

```
  class Design extends StatefulWidget {
        @override
      _DesignState createState() => _DesignState();
        }

      class _DesignState extends State<Design>{
      var Data;

     @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
        comparer().then((List returnedV){
         setState(() {
         Data = returnedV;
         });
        });
     }     

    Future<List> compare() async {
    ...
    return dataDevice
    }
  }
  class AboutSheet extends StatefulWidget {
    final List Data;
    AboutSheet({@required this.Data});
      @override
  _AboutSheetState createState() => _AboutSheetState();
  }
  class _AboutSheetState extends State<AboutSheet> {

  }
```

Every time I use the variable Data in the second class it has the value null. I think it's because I have defined it before with the value null and it's pulling that and is not waiting for the future to assign a value to it. I can't think of a workaround. I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is a **state management** solution. There is a lot of them, with each their pros and cons. I *(and the Flutter team)* would suggest **Provider**.

Take a look at this : [List of state management approaches](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)